# Find all accumulation points and the limit superior and the limit inferior of $x_n=n(-1)^n/(2n-1)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $x_n=(n(-1)^n)/(2n-1)$. Prove that $x_n$ is bounded, find all accumulation points of $x_n$ and determine the limit superior and the limit inferior of $x_n$.

1) To prove that it is bounded I kind of got stuck. I tried starting with $(n(-1)^n)/(2n-1) > -n/(2n-1) > -2n/(2n-1) Which doesn't lead to a number... Am I missing something?
2) To find the accumulation points, we clearly see the positive terms tend to 1/2 and the negative terms to -1/2. So, these are the accumulation points. But do we need to prove it mathematically? 
3) For the limit superior and inferior, I would think that it is still 1/2 and -1/2, but for this I am very confused.

Comment: How do you get $-n/(2n-1) > -n/(2n)$ ? The sign here is wrong.

Comment: As for 2), you can argue as follows: If $x$ is an accumulation point, then some subsequence of $x_n$ converges to it; this subsequence must contain either infinitely many $x_n$ with even $n$ or infinitely many $x_n$ with odd $n$ (or both).

Comment: oh wow thanks! stupid mistake

Comment: When it is not $\pm\infty$, the limit superior is always the largest accumulation point. Similarly, when it is not $\pm\infty$, the limit inferior is always the smallest accumulation point. When a sequence is bounded, both inferior ans superior limits are finite.

Comment: So my answers are correct? And thank you that's a good explanation. I didn't want to just have an answer without an explanation

Comment: Yes your answers are correct if you add @darijgrinberg's argument. The actual explanation is in the proofs of these general results, but these proofs are not difficult.

Comment: You still need to proof the boundedness. For this, try to give an upper bound of $|x_n|$.